# Why does my WPF GroupBox looks so weird?

Tags: wpf, styles, groupbox

I have no style set anywhere in my application!
[image]

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce in a simple app with only this in it? If so post the app.

Comment: Maybe you are using a theme that is overriding the default style of the GroupBox.

Comment: This output in which OS XP/Vista/win7?

Comment: I have updated the question with sample xaml in the screenshot. There is no other file setting that style. Its just a test project with one window not more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behavior appears to be the default, **at least under Windows 7**, [according to this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/86daffb8-915a-4fb0-848a-f78b0d61d9a0).

It looks like the `GroupBox` border actually gets an additional white border both inside and outside: just try increasing the `BorderThickness`, and you'll see what I mean.

Also, compare to another control - a `Label`, for instance - and notice that when you define a border around that, even a rounded border, there's no white 'shadow'.

As far as I can tell, the only way around this (if you need one) is to define a `ControlTemplate` for the `GroupBox` yourself. The link posted above contains a good example: notice the answer that sets the `BorderBrush` on those surrounding `Borders` to `Transparent`.

**The canonical example for that custom template can be found [in the `GroupBox` MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750472(v=vs.100).aspx).**

*(On an unrelated note, that `BorderGapMaskConverter` in the example is interesting - that's how the GroupBox knows to render the part of the border beneath the header as transparent... Neat. :))*

Comment: regarding your msdn link there is no answer from any MSFT. Of course this is a Windows 7 bug I very assume... Damn I totally forgot this bounty as I fixed the problem with an own controltemplate last days :P Ok at least you know how to use google go and get away with half of my SO life :/ thx buddy ;-)

Comment: thanks for pointing out the BorderGapMaskConverter ! interesting indeed!

Comment: As someone new to WPF, can someone explain what I would actually do with that template?

Comment: Found a good article on this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084%28v=vs.110%29.aspx